# Injecting CSS into Iframe

Tags: css, jquery, iframe

I have added an iframe to my website.
Within the I-Frame is an area which is not required and I would like to hide.

I have tried to inject CSS into the i-frame using

`Functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Eazy_scripts' );
function Eazy_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('js-iframe', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/iframe.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('js-iframe');
}
```

The script `iframe.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#EazyOpsFrame").on("load", function() {
      let head = $("#EazyOpsFrame").contents().find("head");
      let css = '<style>div.fixed.area{display:none !important}</style>';
  jQuery(head).append(css);
  });
});
```

This doesnt seem to work, are there any recommendations?

Comment: The CSS is probably already loaded at that point. Might be better off just finding the specific element in the contents and using JS to hide it: `$("#EazyOpsFrame").contents().find( 'div.fixed.area' ).hide()`;

Comment: @Howdy_McGee If i Done that... Would `<style>div.fixed.area{display:none !important}</style>` change to `<style>display:none !important</style>`

Comment: You wouldn't need the CSS line at all. JS will add an inline style to the element hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

If the source of the iframe is not on the same domain as the page that the iframe is embedded on, you cannot change contents inside the iframe.

If the iframe's source is on the same domain, add the CSS directly to the source page.

More: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36513940